# Large Sql-server query error

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a fairly large sql-srv query that worked until I added the second outer apply on to it and now I'm not sure how to fix it, here is the query.

```
SELECT     Qualitycontrol.ID, Qualitycontrol.MachineNo, Qualitycontrol.Description,        Qualitycontrol.CreatedTime, Qualitycontrol.ProductCode, Qualitycontrol.WorkOrder, 
          Qualitycontrol.Quantity, Qualitycontrol.ControllerID ,Qc.Comment, Qc.Reason, Qualitycontrol.FirstOffOverride
FROM         Qualitycontrol 
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM QualityControl_Comments
WHERE Qualitycontrol.ID = QualityControl_Comments.QCUID
ORDER BY Qualitycontrol.ID DESC -- whatevet defines order in QualityControl_Comments
) AS Qc 

OUTER APPLY (
SELECT  top 1   ReaderData.ReaderTime, LEFT(controller_scrap_details.personal_info, 4) AS name,      ReaderData.ReaderDate
FROM         controller_scrap_details INNER JOIN
                  ReaderData ON controller_scrap_details.card_id = ReaderData.CardID
WHERE     controller_scrap_details.password = '1111'  AND ReaderData.controllerID =  Qualitycontrol.ControllerID AND ReaderData.dtReading BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, - 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS  DATE)) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, 
                  CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
) AS firstoff  

INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT Qualitycontrol.MachineNo, MAX(Qualitycontrol.ID) MID
FROM Qualitycontrol
GROUP BY Qualitycontrol.MachineNo
) UNQ ON UNQ.MID = Qualitycontrol.ID
WHERE     (Qualitycontrol.CreatedTime BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1,     CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
ORDER BY Qualitycontrol.MachineNo
```

Comment: What is the error? What is expected result? Could you format your query so it would be more readable?

Answer (score 0):

You have one extra `closing parenthesis` in second `Outer apply`.

```
.....
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT  TOP 1   ReaderData.ReaderTime, LEFT(controller_scrap_details.personal_info, 4) AS NAME,      ReaderData.ReaderDate
FROM         controller_scrap_details INNER JOIN
                  ReaderData ON controller_scrap_details.card_id = ReaderData.CardID
WHERE     controller_scrap_details.password = '1111'  AND ReaderData.controllerID =  
Qualitycontrol.ControllerID AND 
ReaderData.dtReading BETWEEN Dateadd(DAY, - 1, Cast(Getdate() AS  DATE)) AND Dateadd(DAY, 1,
                  Cast(Getdate() AS DATE)))
 --) extra parenthesis remove this
 AS firstoff
 ....
```

Comment: wow that simple huu, cant believe i missed that thank you very much